# What jquery video player, plays avi, mp4, mkv, wmv files?

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I am working on a web-based media center app. As a lightweight alternative to having a running  a media center app in linux.

I have a bash script that generates an html file that uses a polaroid display, of all the posters of my downloaded movies.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/polaroidscreenshot.png

Once I click on a movie poster, I want to go to a second page, that will play a locally hosted  video.

I have tried working with jplayer, but have had problems just using the demo code, that it comes with.

Are there jquery or html5 video player's that support standard movie video formats? Such as avi, mp4, mkv and wmv?

Or would I have to convert them to a format that is more usable to the player?

I would rather not have to convert them, that is doable but would be time consuming, and may distort video quality.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Why?,*** there are already web friendly formats of the video. `flv`, `mp4`, `webm` are very good formats, can support high quality too. You don't need to focus on creating such things.

You can use, media player widgets on the website, and let the video play if the client has the supported codec to play the video. But, since this will narrows the visitors to a windows platform, I dont recommend it either.

With that being said, there is a plugin called [jQuery Media Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/) which provides a limited of what you want.

Comment: I am trying to play videos stored locally on my hard drive, not play streaming videos. As such those are generally in the formats of AVI, MP4, WMV or MKV.

Comment: @crosenblum, so what the problem, playing local files shouldn't be a problem as well.

Comment: Been trying to get it to work, just to play the same pages as on the demo pages. I even copied the html straight over and it still didn't work. Does it cause problems if i am running the web page via file:// etc?

Comment: No, in order to access the local file storage, you have to user `file://`

Comment: This is my player.html http://pastebin.com/4GxaT7PX it parses the url variables, then hopefully play's the local file. Atm I can't get it to even play the demo files, and show the movie screen. Can any of you see what I am doing wrong in using the jquery media plugin?

Comment: @crosenblum, Thats a completely different question. Please ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this question was asked, but I just came across it while researching video players.You can always convert video formats using the ffmpeg tool, but as you said, it would be time consuming, and may distort video quality.
Nowadays there are HTML5 video players and it would be a better solution to use them to play the video formats that you mentioned. Here is a blog post about some of the popular HTML5 video players available on the Open Web. 
http://cloudinary.com/blog/html5_video_player